# eclipse "maven->update" throws handshake_failure. "mvn clean install" works

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, ssl

I'm trying to get eclipse to accept a remote repo. Here's my maven settings.xml

```
    <settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
                      https://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
<localRepository/>
<interactiveMode/>
<usePluginRegistry/>
<offline/>
<pluginGroups/>
<servers>
    <server>
        <id>***-releases</id>
        <username>MyUsername</username>
        <password>secret</password>
    </server>

    <server>
        <id>***-snapshots</id>
        <username>MyUsername</username>
        <password>secret</password>
    </server>

    <server>
        <id>***-public</id>
        <username>MyUsername</username>
        <password>secret</password>
    </server>

    <server>
        <id>***-custom-releases</id>
        <username>MyUsername</username>
        <password>secret</password>
    </server>

</servers>
<mirrors>
    <mirror>
        <id>jboss-public</id>
        <name>JBoss Public Nexus Repository</name>
        <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
        <mirrorOf>jboss</mirrorOf>
    </mirror>
    <mirror>
        <id>MyCentral</id>
        <url>http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
        <mirrorOf>central</mirrorOf>
    </mirror>

</mirrors>
<proxies/>

    <profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>repository</id>
        <repositories>
            <repository>
                <id>repository</id>
                <name>repository</name>
                <url>file:/C:/Users/myUsername/.m2/repository/</url>
                <layout>default</layout>
                <releases>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                    <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
                </releases>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>false</enabled>
                    <updatePolicy>daily</updatePolicy>
                </snapshots>
            </repository>
            <repository>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>false</enabled>
                </snapshots>
                <id>***-releases</id>
                <url>https://www.***/nexus/content/repositories/***-releases/</url>
            </repository>
            <repository>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </snapshots>
                <id>***-snapshots</id>
                <url>https://www.***/nexus/content/repositories/***-snapshots/</url>
            </repository>
            <repository>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>false</enabled>
                </snapshots>
                <id>***-public</id>
                <url>https://www.***/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
            </repository>
            <repository>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>false</enabled>
                </snapshots>
                <id>***-custom-releases</id>
                <url>https://www.***.de/nexus/content/repositories/***-custom-releases/</url>
            </repository>
            <repository>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>false</enabled>
                </snapshots>
                <id>fusesource</id>
                <url>http://repo.fusesource.com/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
                <releases>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </releases>
            </repository>
        </repositories>

        <pluginRepositories>
            <pluginRepository>
                <releases>
                    <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
                </releases>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </snapshots>
                <id>***-public</id>
                <url>https://www.***/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
            </pluginRepository>
                            <pluginRepository>
                <releases>
                    <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
                </releases>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </snapshots>
                <id>***-releases</id>
                <url>https://www.***/nexus/content/repositories/***-releases/</url>
            </pluginRepository>
        </pluginRepositories>

    </profile>

</profiles>
<activeProfiles>
    <activeProfile>repository</activeProfile>
</activeProfiles>
```

If I run `mvn clean install` from the terminal or eclipse, the build succeeds. However, if I  click "Maven->Update Project" in Eclipse, I get the following error message:

```
Project build error: Non-resolvable parent POM for ***:***:*** Failure to transfer ***:***:pom:*** from https://www.***/nexus/content/repositories/***-snapshots/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of ***-snapshots has elapsed or updates are forced.
 Original error: Could not transfer artifact ***:***:pom:*** from/to ***-snapshots (https://www.***/nexus/content/repositories/***-snapshots/): Received fatal alert: handshake_failure and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM pom.xml /***    line 4  Maven pom Loading Problem
```

The "'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM" doesn't worry me, since the parent pom is in the remote repository and since there is no connection to it, the error makes sense to me.

In eclipse I've set my maven-installation to ".../myMaven" under "preferences->Maven->Installations". However, in the same menu, eclipse tells me this: "Note: Embedded runtime is always used for dependency resolution". I'm guessing that's the reason why the resolution works when running `mvn clean install` but doesn't work when I'm trying to update the project with eclipse.

I've also set the Environmentvariable 'MAVEN_OPTS' to this:

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=C:\cacerts\trust.jks -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=secret -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=C:\cacerts\PC2***.pfx -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStoreType=pkcs12 -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=secret
```

These settings seem fine to me, since I can build from the terminal. 
How can I bring eclipse to use the same configs when running "update project"?

Comment: Have you tried to set all those -D options to the `default VM arguments` in the current JRE definition (Window > preferences > Java > Installed JREs) ?

Comment: Good idea... But didn't work :/

Comment: Ahm. The only other place I think to set those -D options is in the `-vmargs` in the `eclipse.ini` file.